# Google App Maker Many-to-Many relations

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Google App Maker project where I have a Many-To-Many Relation between 2 tables **A** and **B**.

I can build a page for table **A** where I have a table of related **B** records and add new ones using a dialog.

However, this approach enables me to create new **B** records and associate them to an **A** record but how can I make the user able to select an existing **B** record and associate it to an **A** record via UI?

I will need to have it work both ways (Select **A** records from **B** record page as well).

UPDATE:

I was to accomplish this by creating a separate dialog for selecting existing records which would show all available **B** records in a table widget with a SELECT button on each row. clicking the button will add the record to the **B** related records of the **A** record. However, I know there has to be an automatic way built by Google that will be less work and better design.

Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is a good one, another solution, depending on the number of existing records, is to use the multi-select widget. (You can bind the items to B's datasource, and values to the relation on a record in A. But as I mentioned, this only works well if the number of items in B is small.)

Making this easier is something we've been looking in to, the main challenge is the correct UI in this case depends a lot on the kind of app you're writing.

Comment: Thanks Devin for your reply.
I will mark it as answer as it has all the solutions for the problem in addition to the one I mentioned.
I really hope that there will be a way to achieve this goal in an easier way via the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out the bindings for a multi-select but I think I am right in saying that they are

```
MultiSelect 

Datasource: inherited: A
Values: @datasource.item.B
Option: @datasource.B.items
```

With this that `Values` are/is what you are updating in A(ie. A.B), but the `Options` you are updating it with are listed in B(ie. B.items).

Devin Taylor is right in his assertion that if you have a lot of records it may not work so well.

Comment: this was immensely helpful for figuring out how to actually implement a multiselect - thanks!